# discord.py Rewrite - How to Check if a discord.Member is a bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to check if a `discord.Member` is a bot in this command:

```
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No Reason Provided"):
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```py
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
    if not user.bot:
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully kicked {user}!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't kick a bot!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot)
- [`Member.kick()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.kick)